Error when trying to install MetaGPT in editable mode using pip
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install MetaGPT in editable mode on Windows. Here are the steps I've followed:
(base) D:\>git clone https://github.com/geekan/MetaGPT.git
fatal: destination path 'MetaGPT' already exists and is not an empty directory.
(base) D:\>cd ./MetaGPT
(base) D:\MetaGPT>python --version
Python 3.11.7
(base) D:\MetaGPT>pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///D:/MetaGPT
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have confirmed that both setuptools and pip are up to date, but the problem persists. What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

The problem is from the .git extension you added.
You can either install by running
# no .git extension here
git clone https://github.com/geekan/MetaGPT

Then cd MetaGPT and run pip install --upgrade -e .
or you install by running:
# notice the .git extension in this
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/geekan/MetaGPT.git

See https://pypi.org/project/metagpt/#description
